# Magento2 Unable to send mail: Unknown error, on php 7.2.3

Tags: magento2, error, email, php-7.3

I've created a `custom email` functionality.
It's working fine on the `PHP 7.2.2` version server.
But it's not working on a `PHP 7.2.3` server.

**Case 1**

1. Magento Version:  2.3.3
2. Php version: 7.2.2
   Result: working

**Case 2**

1. Magento Version:  2.3.3
2. Php version: 7.2.3
   Result: Not working
   `Error: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException): Unable to send mail: Unknown error`

Is this related below

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-2-3-0-Unable-to-send-email-Unknown-error/td-p/119595

Please help me with this issue. To sorting issue.

Comment: live sever show error ??? or normal php mail script is working or not ??

Comment: if you created something custom you should share some important code bits